# Can a Cuda warp communicate with a different warp without using shared memory?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I have a kernel where each warp accumulates the sum of a chunk of data.

At the end of the calculation, I have a situation where the last lane of each warp has to send data to the first lane of the next warp.

Currently, this is done via shared memory:

```
__shared__ int previous_warp_last_lane_val[WARPS_IN_X];

auto lane_id = threadIdx.x & 0x1F;
auto warp_id = threadIdx.x >> 5; 

if (lane_id == (warpSize - 1))
{
    // store the last lane value for the next warp
    previous_warp_last_lane_val[warp_id] = data;
}

__syncthreads(); // shared memory, maybe there is a better alternative?

// first lane retrieve the data from the last lane of previous warp 
int prev = 0;
if (lane_id == 0 && warp_id > 0)
{
    
    prev = previous_warp_last_lane_val[warp_id - 1];
}
```

This works, but feels rather inefficient. I have to sync all warps where in theory I only have to synchronize 2.

So is there a more efficient way to achieve the same functionality? Is shared memory the only alternative?

Comment: shared memory is the only sensible alternative.  You could also use global memory but that is going to be slower and even more cumbersome.

Comment: It would be great if the cooperative groups extension would allow tiles that are bigger than one warp (i.e. multiples of 32 threads) and therefore synchronization of a subset of warps in a single block. I guess the hardware doesn't support this.

Comment: Computing several virtual/software block in one CUDA block can sometime help to reduce the number of shared memory operation (typically in reductions) and improve performance. However, this can also make the code more complex and result in a slower execution due to more hardware to be used (eg. more registers, bigger code) regarding the rest of your computation. This is not a silver-bullet solution but the best solution I could find so far to slightly speed up such a case in my CUDA codes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works just fine if all of the warps can be scheduled at the same time on the SM. Various parameters like registers per thread play a role in this, and you can also use profilers to see how the warps are scheduled. You can try reducing *threads per block* and *blocks per grid* to make all the blocks resident. Lastly, [occupancy calculator](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#occupancy-calculator) API helps with this.

```c
__global__ void MyKernel(int *array, int arrayCount) {
    __shared__ int previous_warp_last_lane_val[WARPS_IN_X];

    auto lane_id = threadIdx.x & 0x1F;
    auto warp_id = threadIdx.x >> 5; 

    if (lane_id == (warpSize - 1)) {
        // store the last lane value for the next warp
        previous_warp_last_lane_val[warp_id] = data;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // first lane retrieve the data from the last lane of previous warp 
    int prev = 0;
    if (lane_id == 0 && warp_id > 0){
        prev = previous_warp_last_lane_val[warp_id - 1];
    }
}

int launchMyKernel(int *array, int arrayCount) {
    int blockSize;      // The launch configurator returned block size
    int minGridSize;    // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the
                        // maximum occupancy for a full device
                        // launch
    int gridSize;       // The actual grid size needed, based on input
                        // size
    int sharedMemory;   // Size of the shared memory

    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(
        &minGridSize,
        &blockSize,
        (void*)MyKernel,
        sharedMemory,
        arrayCount);

    // Round up according to array size
    gridSize = (arrayCount + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

    MyKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, sharedMemory>>>(array, arrayCount);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // If interested, the occupancy can be calculated with
    // cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor

    return 0;
}
```